# Default text for SQL scripts

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2012

In MS SSQL Server Management Studio 2012, is it possible to get new scripts to contain some default text?

I want to encourage colleagues to comment their scripts more consistently, so I'd like something like

```
/*
Describe the contents of the script here.
Author: myloginname
*/
```

to automatically appear when you hit CTRL+N.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be able to.

[This article](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AmitBansal/sql-server-bi/21/sql-server-management-studio-tip-change-defaul-templates-for-stored-procedures) mentions some options and gives details of where the text is stored for specific templates.

Try looking in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql
```